# How to make the grid pager's width fill 100%,means flowing to right more closely?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I has a grid with many column,and I set the grid overflow-x:scroll,but it seems that that the pager not to automatic lengthening when I  drag to scroller? How to make the pager  flow to right more closely?
The picture is here:
           [Init Pager location:](https://www.yousendit.com/download/WFJYeW40QTZ6RThYRHNUQw)

[The location that I want the pager like](https://www.yousendit.com/download/WFJYeW53Mm1EbUpqQThUQw)

Comment: Pictures don't contain the code. Post your code too

Comment: One up vote? really ?

Comment: Despite of your images, not sure which is the problem. Check the following JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/teGQE/1/) that allows to scroll through the columns while the page stays always visible. Realize that only the header and body of the grid are actually affected by the overflow.

Comment: As the JSFiddle,I just want to set the grid width scroll, and height automatically grow,not fix height and not scroll height.

Comment: Here is my code,I find the result that the pager and scroller is in the opposite direction.How to correct it?Here is the link:http://jsfiddle.net/whoamiwho/teGQE/2/